# Regex: find only numbers in a string

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have a string

```
K9908098F, G2342D34324/ 234234323, 234-234-234; R324234
```

How to catch only `234234323` and `234-234-234` in VBA?

This `[\d-]+` pattern grabs extra pieces

Comment: @Will_Panda all digit lines: e.g. `9908098` or `34324`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close, just need to add borders: `\b[\d-]+\b`

[Regex demo and explanation](https://regex101.com/r/UYTKK7/1)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

[`(\w+),\s+([\w-]+);`](https://regex101.com/r/t0c43G/1)

This will capture `234234323` in group 1 and `234-234-234` in group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Not too elegant though but would work. Just a small addition to your regex.

```
[\d-]+[,;]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this too,

```
[-\d]+(?=[;,. ])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pWcwXa/4)